# convert a console app to a windows app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

(its a long story) but I have a large complex project file containing a windows program. Unfortunately the project was originally built as a console app. The program compiles and links ok but when runs brings up a console instead of the collection of windows I was hoping for. I looked at the command line and saw "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE" whereas it should be "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS". I have no idea how to change the command line. Is there some box I can tick in the project setting somewhere to make this change?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Right-click the project icon in the Solution Explorer, then **Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem**, and set that to **Windows**.  You'll also have to change your `main()` method to `WinMain()`.  And you'd better create some windows or there won't be much to look at.

Answer (score 13):

Complementing Hans' answer: While under Properties, also remember to expand the **C/C++** node and select **Preprocessor**. Then edit the **Preprocessor Definitions** - replace `_CONSOLE` with `_WINDOWS`.

Comment: _WINDOWS undefined if the Windows subsystem set in linker