# How to change file type between Windows Application and Console

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I think in my recent project I accidentally had one `cpp` file set up as a Windows application and the other `cpp` file as a console file. No matter what I did I ended up with weird errors saying I needed a `WinMain()` function, or that a `WinMain()` function was causing half-a-dozen errors. Does anybody know of a way to switch a Windows Application file's settings to a console application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884124/convert-a-console-app-to-a-windows-app

Comment: @GoverNator That answer is for Visual Studio.

Comment: `project options -> general`, change the type

Comment: It should be project file, a cpp file will not contain any project settings, nor will it know it is GUI or console application.

Comment: Removed tag from title and improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the subsystem for your linker via the switch **/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE** . When doing so no WinMain() will expected any more. You should do this in the used makefile which was written / created by Dev C++.